# Double integral by changing Order of integration

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Evalute $\int^2_1\int^{\ln(x)}_0(x-1)\sqrt{1+e^{2y}}dydx$

[image: The solution by OP]

I stuck at the above process....Could anyone help me with it?

Comment: What's your actual issue? Both $\int_{1}^{2}\sqrt{1+m^2}\,dm$ and $\int_{1}^{2}m\sqrt{1+m^2}\,dm$ are fairly simple integrals.

Comment: the latter one is easily integrated. Bur as for $\int_{1}^{2}\sqrt{1+m^2}\,dm$ Can it be solved without using trigonometric substitution? It is a question that needs to be done in 2 minutes, I suppose there may be some trick....

Comment: By parts, for instance. It is related to $[\text{arcsinh}(m)]_1^2$.

Comment: Oh, got it. Looks like the only way to evaluate the former part is to integrate by part using trigonometric substitution. Thanks for your quick reply !